# Outputing a message without killing the script

Tags: php

I am working on a website that generates pins that are used for the registration of vehicles, my problem here is, when i want to generate a lot of pins like 50,000 pins at once, this will take a very long time to complete, what i want is a way to generate the pins in the background while my browser loads to a page that will display a message saying 'your pins are being generated' instead of waiting for the 50,000 pins to generate before displaying a message. Am using PHP AND MYSQL.

Comment: I don't think a website is the proper way to do this. I'd rather do this in a more specialized application, or maybe just a php script that is called in a cron job. The website could poll if the job is ready.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response, but the cron job in my web hosting server doesn't run every second but every minute.

Answer (score 1):

you could split that in 2 pages: One php script to generate your pins and another to show the message to your user.

This is an approach to show the message to your user:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function GeneratePINS(quantity)
{
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater('pinsAjax','generate_pins.php?quantity='+quantity,
    {
        method : 'get',
    }) ;
}

}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="GeneratePINS(5000);">
Generating pins...
</body>
</html>
```

And your generate_pins.php should be like this:

```
<?php
$DEFAULT_VALUE = 100;
$quantity = (isset($_GET['quantity']) && is_numeric($_GET['quantity'])) ? $_GET['quantity'] : $DEFAULT_VALUE;

echo YOUR_METHOD_TO_GENERATE_PINS(quantity);
?>
```

Dot forget to download the prototype JS here: http://www.prototypejs.org/download

I Hope that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a task daemon. Then you simply start a task and get an unique ID which you can then use on the "please wait.." page to poll if the results are available (of course polling is not the cleanest solution but the easiest one).

There seems to be a [PHP client for celery](https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php); but you'll still need to write the code of your actual tasks in Python. Maybe there are pure-PHP solutions available, too.